# ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ImporterController):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redmine, rails-routing

my route.rb file looks like

```
RedmineApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'importer/:action', :controller => 'importer'
end
```

error I  got  is

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ImporterController):
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:219:in `constantize'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:218:in `each'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:218:in `constantize'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:69:in `  controller_reference'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:54:in `controller'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
rack-openid (1.4.2) lib/rack/openid.rb:98:in `call'
pdfkit (0.5.4) lib/pdfkit/middleware.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'

rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:55
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:50
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

my rails -v is 3.2.11 ruby -v is 1.8.7
i am importing to_csv Plug-in in Red mine and I got this error

Comment: `controller` names are are plural.  The error says that it cannot find `ImporterController`, so try updating `:controller => 'importer'` to `:controller => 'importers'`.

Comment: if it doesn't work it is because you don't have the controller file set up correctly, in the correct directory, with the correct inheritance from actioncontroller

Comment: i tries both in controller file and route file but no luck!!!

Comment: Try something as
get "/importer" => "importers#some_action"
post "/importer" => "importers#some_action"

Comment: Just trying a shot in the dark here. Does the controller file name match with the class name. If the controller name is ImporterController then the file name needs to be importer_controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
match '/importers/action_name' => 'importers#action_name'
```

and one more thing controller name is plural

so correct importer to importers.

Comment: Ok then use this match '/importer/action_name' => 'importer#action_name'   thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax

```
match 'importers', to: 'importers#action', via: [:get, :post]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you controller is a child of `ApplicationController`

`ImporterController < ApplicationController`